# Update of blog site via cron does not work

Tags: ruby, git, cron, rvm, octopress

Currently i have blog site which works with [Octopress](http://octopress.org) in relationship with Git but currently facing a problm that i can't update the site automatically via a cron triggered script. I'm using a script (update.sh) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
export PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/:/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm:$PATH
cd /usr/local/repositories 
cd supose.git
git fetch -q --all
cd /usr/local/vhost/octopress
git pull
rake generate
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/jekyll generate
```

But i alway get the following error message:

```
+ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
+ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/jekyll generate
invalid command. Use --help for more information
```

I know there must be a relationship with the environment, but i can't get the point to get it running.

If i login into the machine and cd into the folder and do `rake generat` it works like a charm.

Comment: Added `+ [[ -s /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] + source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to my script and it works. Please copy your comment as an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `PATH` you have when you login against the one `crontab` gives you. It may be quite different. `rvm` does other things as well as set the path. You'll need to make sure our `PATH` is correct, and run the script that rvm puts in your `login` profile `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`. You could try running `. ~/.bash_profile ; (path_to_script)/update.sh` as the `crontab` command.

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing PATH use a wrapper - this will provide environment for your ruby:

```
rvm wrapper ruby-2.0.0-p247 --no-links rake jekyll
```

and then use it like this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/rake   generate
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/jekyll generate
```